# Configuring AppCheck for local development in Angular applications

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, firebase-tools, firebase-app-check

I'm using Firebase with it's different products like Auth, Firestore, Functions and now want to integrate AppCheck. I'm using Angular and therefore I'm using the [AngularFire library](https://github.com/angular/angularfire).

To develop locally, I'm using the Firebase Emulator Suite with a demo project as described [here in the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth?hl=en#choose_a_firebase_project). It's great that no real Firebase environment is affected with a demo project. Setting all that up with Firestore, Auth and Functions worked well.

Now with AppCheck, I do not find a way to configure the application so that it works with a real Firebase project or the emulator suite depending on the current environment. The goal is to not have different builds for a dev, prod environment but instead determine the current environment dynamically for example based on the current browser URL.

The [samples of the AngularFire repo](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/samples/modular/src/app/app.browser.module.ts) only show a configuration based on the environment files in Angular which requires different builds for different environments.

So my question in the end is:

**Is there a way to configure AppCheck in Angular applications to work with and without a real Firebase project in one single build? If yes, how to do that?**